# How can I get the host IP while using AWS Amplify

Tags: aws-amplify, peerjs

I made a React web app and deployed it using AWS Amplify. In addition to hosting the website the host is also running a peerjs server so that the clients can use peer-to-peer connection. The problem is that in order for a peer to connect to the peerjs server it needs the IP address that the server is running on.

So how can I get the host's IP address?